# Gatling - load model with peaks

Tags: gatling

Is there a way to run a gatling test with a steady state og lets say 3 users per second, but periodically increase the load to lets say 10 user, lasting one minute and then back to 3 users. Repeating this "up and down" in load for 1 hour i.e.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first need define unique step with your flat and ramp load:

```
val loadStep = List(
    constantUsersPerSec(3) during (10 minutes),
    constantUsersPerSec(10) during (1 minutes),
  )
```

Then we populate with necessary steps count (via method fill)

```
 val loadProfile = List.fill(3)(loadStep).flatten
```

Output will be:

```
constantUsersPerSec(3) during (10 minutes),
constantUsersPerSec(10) during (1 minutes),
constantUsersPerSec(3) during (10 minutes),
constantUsersPerSec(10) during (1 minutes),
constantUsersPerSec(3) during (10 minutes),
constantUsersPerSec(10) during (1 minutes),
```

And then need to pass **loadProfile** variable into scenario inject method